# split lc connection to fit two SMF transcievers?

Tags: networking, switch, fibre-channel, fiber

I got a cross connect in a data center patched into my patch panel,

I'm using SC to LC cable (SC from patch panel to LC into transceiver)  to connect it to my switch (Arista 7150s).

I just bought another switch mostly for backup purposes in case of hardware failure, but was wondering, is it possible to "split" the LC to fit into two transceivers?

I noticed some posts about couplers & splitters but not really sure not understand how that works.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Most fiber transceivers use one fiber strand per direction, so you need two strands per link.

There are also "BX"-style transceivers using two different wavelengths, one per direction. As far as I know, these only exist for 1 Gbit/s (IEEE 1000BASE-BX10) and 10 Gbit/s ("10GBASE-BX" non-standard). These only use a single strand and you can split the usually duplex SC-LC patch cables into two simplex cables.